# Flutter - Error: Can't find ')' to match '('. 'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed. Error

Tags: android, flutter

When I run my Flutter app I get few errors like this:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:30: Error: Can't find ')' to match '('.
          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.
                             ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:33: Error: Expected ',' before this.
          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.
                                ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:43: Error: Expected ',' before this.
          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.

                                          ^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:47: Error: Expected ',' before this.
          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.
                                              ^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:52: Error: Expected ',' before this.
          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.
                                                   ^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:58: Error: Expected ',' before this.
          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.

                                                         ^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:64: Error: Expected ',' before this.
          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.

                                                               ^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:64: Error: Undefined name 'disposed'.
          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.

                                                               ^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:31: Error: Undefined name 'A'.
          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.
                              ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:33: Error: Undefined name 'FocusNode'.
          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.
                                ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:43: Error: Undefined name 'was'.

          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.
                                          ^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:47: Error: Undefined name 'used'.
          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.
                                              ^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:52: Error: Undefined name 'after'.
          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.

                                                   ^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:58: Error: Undefined name 'being'.
          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.
                                                         ^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:148:16: Error: Method not found: 'nFlutterError'.
          'A ${nFlutterError (A FocusNode was used after being disposed.
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I used FocusNode in my project. Since I got this error later, I removed the `FocusNode` codes in case the problem would be solved. But the error persists. I put the `FocusNode` codes on the login and sign up pages.

This is the first time I have encountered this error while dealing with Flutter and I have no idea how to solve it. How can I solve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you include sample widget

Comment: I recommend updating your flutter version. I can see [in the latest builds](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart) that they have fixed this error. It looks like the error you are getting is in the framework it's self.

Comment: @returnVoid My flutter version is already up to date. Latest version.